# Odd Newline Behaviour in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am migrating from **Windows Forms in VB** to **WPF C#** and I wrote the following code....

```
namespace TestWPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OutputBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        }

        private void AcceptButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OutputBox.AppendText(String.Format("You clicked the button.{0}",Environment.NewLine));
        }
    }
}
```

Where `OutputBox` is a `RichTextBox`.

Upon running the program and clicking the button a few times I get output like the following....

```
You clicked the button.You clicked the button.

You clicked the button.

You clicked the button.
```

Why does the 1st newline not appear, and then it inserts blank lines rather than just moving on to the next line.

If I change the code to

```
.AppendText(String.format("You clicked the button.{0}OK{0}",environment.NewLine
```

I get output

```
You clicked the button.

OKYou clicked the button.

OK

You clicked the button.

OK
```

What should my code be like to get output....

```
You clicked the button.
You clicked the button.
You clicked the button.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Environment.NewLine` use `"\r"`. Although I can't find any link now, I think there's a bug in how `RichTextBox` handles `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: its not so much a bug as a misunderstanding of how its designed to work, \r\n is converted to a RTF `\par` not a `\line`and a paragraph doesn't act like a linefeed